# MSAL B2C Browser signup sign in user flow

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I am a using B2C MSAL Browser.js

I have a working sign up sign in flow however when I want to pass a extraQueryParameter to the sign up page it get's cleared after the user hit's the sign up button.

```
const request = {
    scopes: [process.env.id],
    extraQueryParameters: { id: "123" },
  };

 msalInstance.loginRedirect(request);
```

I can see at the login the the query parameter get's added but when I hit sign up it get's removed, is there a way to pass it to the sign up, or hit the sign up page directly without having to create separate user flows?

Comment: What do you need to do with it at sign up page?

Comment: fill in some fields automatically so the user doesn't have to type them in.

Comment: You need to use claims resolvers on the sign up technical profile within the input claims section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

Comment: With user flows, you can’t achieve this.

Comment: Sorry if I am a little confused here. Where does one put a claim resolver? So you are saying even if I user a signup only user flow I can't autopopulate a forms fields from the query parameters in the url, even if I turn on client side JS in the page and try and grab the url parameters and populate the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: You have to use custom policies.

To amplify what @JasSuri said:

The parameter is in the [query string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#oauth2-key-value-parameters)

At the end of the authentication request, you could have:

....&id=123

In the technical profile for sign up, add:

```
<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
```

to the metadata.

Assume "queryID" is a textbox on the sign-up page.

Then have an input claim in your sign up:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="queryID" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:id}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
```

You can then also use "queryID" in your user journey.

Comment: ok so if I use custom policies, can I still use MSAL browsers JS library, or how do I call the custom policy from my app, I see there is a template I can use of xml files for the custom policies, but how do I integrate it in my app?

Comment: In terms of the applications, there is no difference between built-in and custom. So you can still use the same library. If you click the Run function for custom, you see the URL that you need the app to call. But in terms of the app. it's just a different clientID etc.

Comment: Ok I think I have a better Idea now, I will test when Im back to work. Thanks